# How to get Png files of Font awesome icons?

Tags: font-awesome

I make unity game and I need icons.

I think that font awesome icons are the best.

How to get .png files of these icons?

I can't put css in unity game.

I tried to download other icons, but these images are bad.

Comment: http://iconion.com/posts/how-to-convert-font-awesome-to-png-icons-k.html

Comment: I need a free commercial license

Comment: Can you not use the Font Awesome font within Unity?

Comment: It is very uncomfortably.... and it will look worse.

Comment: better use the below python script to convert font-awesome icon css into png https://github.com/odyniec/font-awesome-to-png

Comment: With regards to the fa2png site that was mentioned, it has been down for a while unfortunately. Since I was also an avid user of the site, I spun up an alternative that should give you what you need. [Cleanicons.xyz](https://cleanicons.xyz)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the python script to convert fontawesome icons into png with some custom needs like size, pixels and colors ... please find the below github link to know more...
https://github.com/odyniec/font-awesome-to-png

Answer (score 2):

For all PHP developers !

This one helps me a lot : 
https://github.com/exiang/php-font-awesome-to-png

Especially for font-awesome , developer can modify icons.data.php and can add his custom code into icons.data.php file and generate the image !

This script can also work with other Fonts , we just need to find out cheat-sheet and load it on icons.data.php file , this script will automatically generate the icons.